# select records where columns value not change

Tags: sql

I've a table with column name ID, Date and Value. The value is expected to change daily. However there are some cases where the value remain unchanged. So i want to create a sql query to select ID where the Value haven't been change for 3 days. I illustrate the table as below. Thanks in advance for any help.

e.g. current date is 29Nov. So the query must check value for the past 3 days.

```
    ID   Date   Value
    B99  28nov  400
    B99  27nov  120
    B99  26nov  120
    B99  25nov  300
    A12  28nov  800
    A12  27nov  800
    A12  26nov  800
    A12  25nov  800
    C45  28nov  100
    C45  27nov  260
    C45  26nov  230
    C45  25nov  230
```

So the query should return A12.

Comment: What is your RDBMS and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Why is there a new row for each day?  Why not just create a new record when the values change?  What happens if the 'current day' record is missing?  Or if there are gaps?  What happens if it goes back to the 'three days ago' value?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify your RDBMS but this solution can probably be transposed onto most. I'm the assumption that non-`null` readings are present for each day:

**PostgreSQL 9.1 Schema Setup**:

```sql
create table foo(id text, changed_on date, val integer);
insert into foo(id, changed_on, val)
values ('B99', to_date('2012-11-28','yyyy-mm-dd'), 400),
       ('B99', to_date('2012-11-27','yyyy-mm-dd'), 120),
       ('B99', to_date('2012-11-26','yyyy-mm-dd'), 120),
       ('B99', to_date('2012-11-25','yyyy-mm-dd'), 300),
       ('A12', to_date('2012-11-28','yyyy-mm-dd'), 800),
       ('A12', to_date('2012-11-27','yyyy-mm-dd'), 800),
       ('A12', to_date('2012-11-26','yyyy-mm-dd'), 800),
       ('A12', to_date('2012-11-25','yyyy-mm-dd'), 800),
       ('B99', to_date('2012-11-28','yyyy-mm-dd'), 100),
       ('B99', to_date('2012-11-27','yyyy-mm-dd'), 260),
       ('B99', to_date('2012-11-26','yyyy-mm-dd'), 230),
       ('B99', to_date('2012-11-25','yyyy-mm-dd'), 230)
;
```

**Query**:

```sql
select id
from foo
where changed_on>=to_date('2012-11-29','yyyy-mm-dd')-3
group by id
having count(distinct val)=1
```

**Results**:

```sql
|  ID |
-------
| A12 |
```

[Here's the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e3cfb/3) if you want to play around or adjust the syntax for another RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

What if you will add column with date of change? You can use next condition
 `WHERE ((GetDate() - dateOfChange) / 86400) > 3.`

Comment: -1 : Will not work for any date ranges dealing with daylight savings time.  Additionally, is (potentially, I'm not sure which one you're referring to) dependent on RDBMS-specific behavior, which has not been specified.  Also, is too simplistic for the example data.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM   Table t1
       INNER JOIN
       Table t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID AND t2.Date=DATEADD(day, -1, t1.Date) AND t1.Value=t2.Value
       INNER JOIN
       Table t3 ON t1.ID=t3.ID AND t3.Date=DATEADD(day, -2, t1.Date) AND t1.Value=t3.Value
WHERE  t1.Date=@WhateverDateYouWant
```

the first join matches with the same ID from yesterday if the values are the same and the next with the day before. If you are not storing the date as dates a) why not? and b) you will need to convert the text to as well.